# Hierarchical facets to shown for term names indexed into Solr

Tags: search, solr, drupal

We have a search page in our Drupal project that is built on Solr. Currently, the facets implemented on the search pages are based on taxonomies associated with the content shown in the search results. However, instead of indexing term IDs in Solr, we have indexed the term names. Therefore, when clicking on any of the facet items, the term name is passed as a query to Solr, for example: f[0]=industry:Bioenergy.

Now, the challenge I'm facing is as follows: I want to display the facets in a hierarchical fashion. To achieve this, I have arranged the items in the taxonomy in a hierarchical manner. However, I don't see an option to show the current filters in a hierarchical fashion because I have indexed the term names into Solr instead of the IDs. If I create the facet using the field that references the taxonomy, the term IDs are indexed into Solr, and I can see an option to show that facet in a hierarchical fashion.

I don't want to change the facets because the search URLs are referred to in multiple places, and indexing IDs into Solr will change the URL parameters on the search page. For example, the parameter f[0]=industry:Bioenergy will change to f[0]=industry:1234.

Could you please advise on how I can deal with this situation?